# add a character before a line with matching pattern

Tags: bash, shell, test

I have an array that contains

```
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
line number 4
line number 5
```

Then I ask for the user input:

```
read userInput
echo $userInput
```

And then I try to match the user input, which is a number to my array

```
for i in "${!array[@]}";do
if [["${array[$i]}"="$userInput"]]
then
    echo "~"
    echo " $i"
fi
done
```

But this doesn't work. 
The desire output is this:

```
4
line number 1
line number 2
line number 3
~line number 4
line number 5
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: There are spaces missing: `if [[ "${array[$i]}" = "$userInput" ]]`

Comment: What is your current output with your current code?

Comment: It said command not found on the if line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional `[[ .. ]]` needs whitespace around the operators and values, i.e.

```
[[ "${array[$i]}" = "$userInput" ]]
  instead of 
[["${array[$i]}"="$userInput"]]
```

(The latter is interpreted as one word, and the shell tries to find a command with that name.)

Also, `${!array[@]}` gives you the indexes to the array. I'm not sure if that's what you want, since in the script you print out the index with `echo $i`, but your sample output seems to contain the string stored in the array. If don't need the indices in particular, you can just use `for value in "${array[@]}"`.

Then, if you want to match a partial pattern, you need to explicitly tell the shell that anything before and after the pattern should be accepted: `[[ "$var" = *$pattern* ]]` (no quotes around the pattern). (See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs))

So, paraphrasing a bit:

```
A=("abc" "def" "ghi")
pat=e
for val in "${A[@]}"; do 
    [[ "$val" = *$pat* ]] && echo -n "~"
    echo "$val"
done
```

prints

```
abc
~def
ghi
```

Comment: I tried this and I got pat: command not found

Comment: nevermind I got it to work :) Thanks a ton

Comment: ${array[$i]} is the result of trying different thing with my code, initially I also use ${array[@]}

Comment: @K.U, did you perhaps put spaces around the assignment? As in `pat = something`? They don't belong there. Anyways, of course you can set the variable with `read`, I just used a straight assignment to simplify the example. Note that `"${array[@]}"` needs quotes around it to be useful, without them you get word-splitting.